# What is $delta for in Field API hook_field_widget_form?

Tags: entities

[d.o](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7) defines it as such:

> $delta The order of this item in the array of subelements (0, 1, 2, etc).

So that you can use it as an index into the $items array, but i can't seem to wrap my head around when the $items array would have more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [my question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-fielddelta-content-type-offered-in-contextual-filter) re; delta field in views.  I got an answer for $delta as well.

Comment: I read yours but i didn't quite understand at the time...  do you know how to specify a multi-valued field?  None of the hooks in the Field API seem to explain a way.

Comment: Sorry, I am just beginning to venture into php coding. I am at the idiot level.

Comment: Lol, well atm it seems that i can successfully disregard it and still able to create my custom field.  If i run into an issue, i'll comment back.