# How to filter for a specific delta value in a multi-value field with Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a userStats field with multiple integer values on the profile and I would like to have a View that only shows those users where the **9th value** of the userStats is higher than 4. I thought this can be implemented with the delta filter on multi-field values, but I cant get it to work.

The accepted answer here suggests that it is possible [What is the meaning of the field:delta content type offered in contextual filters in views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-fielddelta-content-type-offered-in-contextual-filter) .

[image]Is this only working for contextual filters, but not static ones?

**SOLUTION**

This seems to work: Adding a the userStats field to display and set the value in the multiple field settings (e.g. show 1, start at position 9). This shows not the whole userStats, but only the one delta. In Views Distinct settings (from the views distinct module) on can filter the repeats (as each delta would create a separate row).

In the filter section of Views one can then easily filter for values higher than 4. Finally, one needs to add a filter delta=9 to show only the value of the specific field 9.
[image]